# Python not found pyenv-win

Tags: python, pyenv

I have pyenv for windows installed, and the command works. I created global and local versions of python. However, when I run `python /m venv .venv`, a message says "python was not found: run without arguments to install...".

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks